# Filling in NaN's when taking the diff between rows of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
index  X    Y
0      5.0  3.0
1      6.0  NaN      
2      7.0  NaN
3      8.0  NaN
4      9.0  3.5
5      10.0 3.25
```

What I would like to do is take the difference between each row, ignoring the NaN values, but filling in places where an NaN exists with the diff between the non-NaN rows. The output `df_diff` should look like so:

```
index  X    Y
0      NaN  NaN
1      1.0  -0.5      
2      1.0  -0.5
3      1.0  -0.5
4      1.0  -0.5
5      1.0   0.25
```

The NaN's are semi-random, and will not always appear at consistent locations. For application purposes, this method will yield a constant slope between row index 0 and row index 4, but I have other pandas operations that are contingent on this kind of dataframe structure further downstream. Using DataFrame.diff, is it possible to generate such an output in Pandas? Any help is appreciated, and thank you!

Answer (score 4):

you can play with back filling (`bfill`) the values, calculate the `diff`, `mask` where it is nan in the original `shift`ed dataframe and then forward fill (`ffill`) the difference calculated before.

```
new_df = (df.bfill()
            .diff()
            .mask(df.shift().isna())
            .ffill()
         )
print(new_df)
     X     Y
0  NaN   NaN
1  1.0  0.50
2  1.0  0.50
3  1.0  0.50
4  1.0  0.50
5  1.0 -0.25
```

Comment: Could you please modify it for groups? Like if example has one more column that divides data in 2 groups: first 3 rows and another 3